# ReportExecutionService Fails on 2016

Tags: asp.net

We copied an asp.net website from a 2008R2 Windows and SQL Server server to a Windows 2016 server with SQL Server 2016 and when we try to open the website from a browser it fails with the following error and stack trace.

```
    Message: E:\shared\apps\RepairTrak\About.aspx.vb(19): error BC30002: Type 'ReportExecutionService' is not defined.

 Stack Trace:
   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Below is the entire code-behind page named About.aspx that is throwing the error.

```
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution
```

Partial Class About
    Inherits Page

```
Private Sub About_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim virtualFolderPath As String = "~/Photos/_Rotated/"
    'Get information about the files in the specified folder
    Dim strPhysicalPath As String = Server.MapPath(virtualFolderPath)
    strPhysicalPath &= "IMG_061749.JPG"

    'Get information about the image
    'Dim currentImage As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(strPhysicalPath)

    ImageRounded.ImageUrl = strPhysicalPath
    ImageThumb.ImageUrl = strPhysicalPath

    ' ReportExecution object prepare   
    Dim rs As New ReportExecutionService()


End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to install the ReportViewer runtime exe on the new server.